# How to STRING_AGG rows from UNNEST?

Tags: google-bigquery

Basically I am new to BigQuery, and I've tried retrieving data by using `STRING_AGG` and `UNNEST`.

[image: I have an object:]

What I am trying to retrieve is for each `PricingModel` the `PriceOptions` in the following format:
`$m/nm` where `n` stands for the `PriceOption` `duration`, and `m` for the `PriceOption` `price`.

However I want to concatenate the results i.e. the `$m/nm` of each `PriceOption` for each `PricingModel`, to get an output like:

```
Row     PriceOptions
__________________________
1       $1/5m,$2/10m,$3/20m
2       $5/25m,$6/40m,$7/60m
```

What I've tried is the following query:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG((select concat(concat(concat('$', price), '/'), concat(duration, 'm')) from unnest(pricingmodel.priceoptions))) as priceOptions
from `mytable.event` limit 100;
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead (very light adjustment to your original query)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('$', price), '/'), CONCAT(duration, 'm'))) 
    FROM UNNEST(pricingmodel.priceoptions)
  ) AS priceOptions
FROM `mytable.event` 
LIMIT 100
```

Also, try to use shortened version of all these CONCATs as

```
STRING_AGG('$' || price || '/' || duration || 'm')
```

Comment: thanks. That did the trick, and it made my query more concise, and readable :D